# Speed up SVN with local repository?

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I work with somewhat large SVN repositories that are located very far from me. Doing SVN history related commands is very painful. Rather, just using any of SVN is pretty painful. I only need to push my changes maybe once a week but I still like to commit often instead of doing large commits.

Since SVN repos can only gain new history (ie: history cannot be changed, existing revisions are permanent) it certainly sounds feasible that there would exist an SVN mirror technology. In particular, one that could either does 1 or 2:

1. Create a local SVN mirror which does an initial copy of the ENTIRE repo (not just a simple checkout, I need the entire repo locally to be able to do diffs and such quickly),
2. Create a local git proxied repo which is a copy/migration of the SVN repo.

Comment: First link returned by google when searching for "git svn": http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-and-Subversion

Comment: How would i know to search for "git svn" lol?

Comment: Because you want to combine git and svn. BTW, googling for "Create a local git proxied repo which is a copy/migration of the SVN repo" returns the same link. And this is literally the text you have in your question.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm not sure if I want to go with that approach. It may be better to use an SVN only solution. I tried using git-svn but it failed and created a corrupt repo. This is why I prefer to look towards others who have tried this, instead of spending hours on all these different permutations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an excellent use case for [`git-svn`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html) — it allows you to work locally and efficiently with `git`, including querying the entire history without ever contacting the svn server, all the while keeping the repository synchronized with the remote SVN.

To start using it, simply start off with `git svn clone http://svn.example.com/project/trunk`, which gives you a fully functional `git` repository. When you are ready to push your local commits back to SVN, you do `git svn dcommit`. Getting new SVN commits (and rebasing your local commits to them) is done with `git svn rebase`.

Answer (score 2):

There is in fact a way to mirror a Subversion repository. But first you'll need the ability to install hook scripts  on the "master" repository. Then use `svnsync` to sync each commit to your local mirror. See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.replication for how to set up replication.

Then configure that local mirror/replica as a [write-through proxy](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.extra.writethruproxy) to automatically pass your commits through to the master repository.

Answer (score 1):

Using [the write-through proxy solution](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.extra.writethruproxy) will help you to reduce read times only. Commits are still proxied through the slave, so you won't see any gain when doing imports, commits, etc.

To achieve a real master/slave repository replication, you can use VisualSVN Server's [Multisite Repository Replication feature](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/multisite-replication/). The feature allows you to setup a master repository at your office and multiple **writable slave repositories** at other remote offices.